# Different output from two sql query one having row_number() statement

Tags: sql-server, inner-join, row-number

I have two SQL query,one with row_number() and another without it.I know that by using row_number and partition by statement ,Duplicate values will not occur.But when I execute both the query then some of the rows of row_number query which do not have duplicate values are also not being displayed.
First SQL query with partition by is

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT b.logtime,
                b.beam_current,
                b.beam_energy,
case 
                         when a.st2_vs2_bag1_onoff=0 then c.st2_vs2_bag1_rb ELSE 0 END as st2_vs2_bag1_rb,
                         CASE when a.st2_vs2_bag2_onoff=0  then c.st2_vs2_bag2_rb else '0' END as st2_vs2_bag2_rb,
                         CASE when a.st2_vs2_bag3_onoff=0  then c.st2_vs2_bag3_rb else '0' END as st2_vs2_bag3_rb,
                         CASE when a.st2_vs2_bag4_onoff=0  then c.st2_vs2_bag4_rb else '0' END as st2_vs2_bag4_rb,
                         CASE when a.st2_vs2_bag5_onoff=0  then c.st2_vs2_bag5_rb else '0' END as st2_vs2_bag5_rb,
                         CASE when a.st2_vs2_bag6_onoff=0  then c.st2_vs2_bag6_rb else '0' END as st2_vs2_bag6_rb,
                         CASE when a.st2_vs2_bag7_onoff=0  then c.st2_vs2_bag7_rb else '0' END as st2_vs2_bag7_rb,
                         CASE when a.st2_vs2_bag8_onoff=0  then c.st2_vs2_bag8_rb else '0' END as st2_vs2_bag8_rb,
                         CASE when a.st2_vs2_bag9_onoff=0  then c.st2_vs2_bag9_rb else '0' END as st2_vs2_bag9_rb ,
                         Row_number() OVER(partition BY b.beam_current
                    ORDER BY b.logtime) RN
         from INDUS2_BDS.dbo.DCCT b INNER JOIN(INDUS2_VACUUM.dbo.main_vacuum_analog c inner join INDUS2_VACUUM.dbo.main_vacuum_status a on c.logtime=a.logtime)
                        ON a.LOGTIME = b.LOGTIME
                         WHERE b.logtime between '2014-10-10 07:17:00' and '2014-10-10 08:46:00' and b.beam_current in('10.00','20.02','30.01','39.99','50.00','59.99','70.00','80.01','89.99','99.98','110.06','120.01','129.98','140.02','150.00','159.99','170.00','180.00','189.99','199.97','209.98') 
                AND b.beam_energy BETWEEN '550' AND '551')

                Select logtime,beam_current,beam_energy,st2_vs2_bag1_rb,st2_vs2_bag2_rb,st2_vs2_bag3_rb,st2_vs2_bag4_rb,st2_vs2_bag5_rb,st2_vs2_bag6_rb,st2_vs2_bag7_rb,st2_vs2_bag8_rb,st2_vs2_bag9_rb
                from cte where rn=1 order by logtime
```

Its output is
[image]

Other sql query having same column values and inner join and condition as above is-

```
select b.beam_current, b.beam_energy,case 
                         when a.st2_vs2_bag1_onoff=0 then c.st2_vs2_bag1_rb ELSE 0 END as st2_vs2_bag1_rb,
                         CASE when a.st2_vs2_bag2_onoff=0  then c.st2_vs2_bag2_rb else '0' END as st2_vs2_bag2_rb,
                         CASE when a.st2_vs2_bag3_onoff=0  then c.st2_vs2_bag3_rb else '0' END as st2_vs2_bag3_rb,
                         CASE when a.st2_vs2_bag4_onoff=0  then c.st2_vs2_bag4_rb else '0' END as st2_vs2_bag4_rb,
                         CASE when a.st2_vs2_bag5_onoff=0  then c.st2_vs2_bag5_rb else '0' END as st2_vs2_bag5_rb,
                         CASE when a.st2_vs2_bag6_onoff=0  then c.st2_vs2_bag6_rb else '0' END as st2_vs2_bag6_rb,
                         CASE when a.st2_vs2_bag7_onoff=0  then c.st2_vs2_bag7_rb else '0' END as st2_vs2_bag7_rb,
                         CASE when a.st2_vs2_bag8_onoff=0  then c.st2_vs2_bag8_rb else '0' END as st2_vs2_bag8_rb,
                         CASE when a.st2_vs2_bag9_onoff=0  then c.st2_vs2_bag9_rb else '0' END as st2_vs2_bag9_rb 
                        from INDUS2_BDS.dbo.DCCT b INNER JOIN(INDUS2_VACUUM.dbo.main_vacuum_analog c inner join INDUS2_VACUUM.dbo.main_vacuum_status a on c.logtime=a.logtime)
                        ON a.LOGTIME = b.LOGTIME and (b.beam_current like '%9.96' or b.beam_current like '%9.97' or  b.beam_current like '%9.98' or  b.beam_current like '%9.99'  or  b.beam_current like '%0' or b.beam_current like '%_0.01' or  b.beam_current like '%_0.02' or  b.beam_current like '%_0.03' or  b.beam_current like '%_0.04' or  b.beam_current like '%_0.05' or  b.beam_current like '%_0.06')
                        and b.logtime between '2014-10-10 07:17:00' and '2014-10-10 08:46:00' and b.beam_current in('10.00','20.02','30.01','39.99','50.00','59.99','70.00','80.01','89.99','99.98','110.06','120.01','129.98','140.02','150.00','159.99','170.00','180.00','189.99','199.97','209.98') order by b.beam_current
```

Its output is-
[image]

AS from sql query we can see that both the query have same inner join and where conditions.But the output is different.The reason about this can't be understood.

Comment: `AND b.beam_energy BETWEEN '550' AND '551'`

Comment: Indent you queries properly to see their structure

Comment: yup,I forgot beam_ energy .What a silly mistake I did.Thanks